# How may I Select records with duplicate one column?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

In this table I want to select all the distinct TRANSACTION with latest date and the RECORD_NUMBER of that row. Please check the image for table and desired output

[Please click and see the image of table and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaZd5.png)

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many times. You use ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION BY and then get the rows where the value of ROW_NUMBER = 1

Comment: Thanks Sean! could you please write the query for me or give me a reference?

Comment: Pretty harsh this was closed in 12 minutes. It is the OPs first post. They need some time to be able to add some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked and answered so many times. You use ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION BY and then get the rows where the value of ROW_NUMBER = 1. It was quicker to just write this instead of finding one of the duplicates.

```
select t.TRANSACTION
    , t.RUN_DATE
    , t.RECORD_NUMBER
from
(
    select st.TRANSACTION
        , st.RUN_DATE
        , st.RECORD_NUMBER
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by st.TRANSACTION order by st.RUN_DATE desc)
    from SomeTable st
) t
where t.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean! It worked for me :)